# How can I set up interactions between sprites with Pixi.js?

Tags: pixi.js

I am trying to make sprites interact with each other. I am not a programmer, so I just used the codes for the dragging example and the interactive example from the Pixi.js site, and was able to get draggable sprites that change color when the mouse is on them (and return to normal when it is not).
What I would like to do is to avoid sprites to overlap, and to force them to join (one on the side of the other, or one below the other) when they are close enough.
I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been taking a look to some of the JS files in http://www.goodboydigital.com/runpixierun/. It seems to me that if I can figure out how they make their elements interact, I'll be on the right track. So far, it seems to me that a key element is the isHit (method?).